# Struts 2 + Hibernate not able to solve null pointer

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-s2hibernate

**struts.xml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
                <action name="addEmp" method="add" class="app.web.EmployeeAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**hibernate.chg.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/struts
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">pluto</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="app.domain.User" />
                <mapping class="chapter1.Employee" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Employees.java**

```
package app.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employees {
    private int empId;
    private String empName;

    @Id
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package app.domain;

import chapter1.Employee;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);

        config.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        //new SchemaExport(config).create(true,true);

        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**EmpDAO.java**

```
package app.dao;

import app.domain.Employees;

public interface EmpDAO {
    public void saveEmp(Employees emps);
}
```

**EmpDAOImpl.java**

```
package app.dao;

import app.domain.Employees;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
public class EmpDAOImpl implements EmpDAO {
    @SessionTarget
    Session session;

    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction transaction;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    @Override
    public void saveEmp(Employees emps)
    {
        session.save(emps);
    }
}
```

**EmployeeAction.java**

```
package app.web;

import app.dao.EmpDAO;
import app.dao.EmpDAOImpl;
import app.domain.Employees;
import app.domain.HibernateUtil;
import app.domain.User;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

public class EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport{
  HibernateUtil hu = new HibernateUtil();
    Employees emps = new Employees();

    EmpDAO empDAO;
    public String execute()
    {

        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String add()
    {

        emps = new Employees();
            emps.setEmpId(200);
            emps.setEmpName("sadi");
        empDAO.saveEmp(emps);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Employees getEmps() {
        return emps;
    }

    public void setEmps(Employees emps) {
        this.emps = emps;
    }
}
```

Now i want to pass values in EmployeeAction manually not from a form, so i havent used model driven, I am getting error as shown below, where i am doing wrong

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
app.web.EmployeeAction.add(EmployeeAction.java:40)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.s2hibernatevalidator.interceptor.HibernateValidatorInterceptor.intercept(HibernateValidatorInterceptor.java:123)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.intercept(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

Comment: have you tried debugging it with a debugger?

Comment: First of all i am new to struts and hibernate, so i would like to confirm tht what ever the code i have posted is valid like i have used annotations n all.

Comment: Even the mapping stuff, please guide me, i am sure i have done mistake somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you had is that you didn't initialize the DAO instance `empDAO`. You should do it manually

```
empDAO = new EmpDAOImpl();
```

before using this variable as a left value.

Comment: but i am getting error as EmpDAO is abstract; cannot be instantiated, i dint use the abstract keyword also.

Comment: Ouch, really I didn't see that. Take an instance that is not abstract.

Comment: now what should i do, actuall i am working on an example which implements hibernate, i am trying to do the same thing using struts 2, but i want to manually pass the values.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, pass it manually (hardcoded) or as parameters doesn't matter, but to save the `Employees` (should make it singular) you need the DAO instance that should be instantiated like in this answer before call `empDAO.saveEmp(emps);`.

Comment: Hey ya thats working. I initialized the EmpDAOImpl object directly without using its interface, what i wold like to know how to do it using its interface, how to initialize through the interface, any help will be appreciated please.

Comment: `EmpDAO` is an interface. It should have `saveEmp(Employees e)` method.